# Google Safe browsing API is not responding - sending back response status

Tags: php, json, curl, safe-browsing

I am trying to integrate Google Safe browsing API to my website. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api):

What I have tried:

```
$apiKey = 'MyFakeAPiKey-pozpkefpoqskpfazejsqpi';
$url = 'http://www.bbc.com/';
$url = urlencode($url);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=firefox&key='. $apiKey.'&appver=1.5.2&pver=4.0&url='.$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Content-length: auto";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

echo print_r($result, true);
```

I get no response.What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If that is your real API key you should invalidate it **_immediately_**. It is forever compromised, and you need to generate a new one.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I noted in the bottom of the question that this key is not real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Everything works as expected.

```
  $url = 'http://911.sos-empleados.net';


                  $apiKey = 'Your API';
                  $apiUrl = 'https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key='.$apiKey;

                  $params = [
                      'client' => [
                          'clientId' => 'foobar',
                          'clientVersion' => '1.2.3'
                      ],
                      'threatInfo' => [
                             "threatTypes" =>["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
                            "platformTypes" => ["WINDOWS"],
                             'threatEntryTypes' => ['URL'],
                          'threatEntries' => [
                              [ 'url' => $url ]
                          ]
                      ]
                  ];


                  $ch = curl_init($apiUrl);
                  curl_setopt_array($ch, [
                      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                      CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
                      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($params),
                      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                          'Content-Type: text/json'
                      ]
                  ]);

                  $res = curl_exec($ch);
                  ?> <pre><?php echo print_r($res, true); ?></pre> <?php
                  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of the API. The endpoint in your code corresponds to version 1 of the Safe Browsing API, which was deprecated in December 2011, and which has since been shut down.

You will need to update to a supported version of the API -- preferably v4, as that's current.

Comment: Deprecated is not equal to not working. I managed to get both v3 and v4 working, but of course stayed with v4. And the answer I have provided is for v4.

Comment: What has been deprecated -- and subsequently shut down, although I can't find an exact date -- is **version 1** of the Safe Browsing API. (As well as version 2.) Later versions are fine, but the code you initially posted was specific to the old, nonfunctional, version of the API.

Answer (score 0):

**An empty response is normal for this API.**

[API version 4](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api) returns an empty object if the url is not found in the database:

```
{}
```

If the url is found in the database, it returns an object like this:

```
{
    "matches": [{
        "threatType": "MALWARE",
        "platformType": "ALL_PLATFORMS",
        "threat": {
            "url": "http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware/"
        },
        "cacheDuration": "300s",
        "threatEntryType": "URL"
    }]
}
```

You can use this url to check:
***http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware/***